# Como fazer INSERT em três tabelas com Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, query

Preciso realizar um **insert** em três tabelas relacionadas na mesma query.  Tenho o seguinte cenário: `Cidade, Estado e Pais`

Como posso construir uma **stored procedure** em Sql Server para isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem várias formas ! Em uma **PROCEDURE** você pode criar a sua lógica .

Vou dar um exemplo, porém não entendi exatamente o que você quer fazer e não tenho a estrutura da sua tabela

Com o seguinte esquema:

```
create table pais(cod_pais int identity primary key,nome nvarchar(50))
go
create table estado(cod_estado int identity primary key,cod_pais int foreign key references pais,nome nvarchar(50))
go
create table cidade(cod_cidade int identity primary key,cod_estado int foreign key references estado,nome nvarchar(50));
go
```

Você pode criar uma **procedure** que insere **pais**, **estado** e **cidade** juntos :

```
create procedure InserirTudoJunto @nome_pais nvarchar(50) , @nome_estado nvarchar(50) , @nome_cidade nvarchar(50) 
as
begin
  begin transaction t
    begin try  
        declare @ids table (cod_pais int,cod_estado int);
        insert into pais (nome) output inserted.cod_pais into @ids(cod_pais) values ('Brasil');
        insert into estado (nome,cod_pais) output inserted.cod_estado into @ids(cod_estado) values (@nome_estado,(select cod_pais from @ids));
        insert into cidade (nome,cod_estado) values(@nome_cidade,(select cod_estado from @ids where cod_estado is not null));
        commit transaction t
    end try
    begin catch
        rollback transaction t
    end catch
end
```

E agora pra rodar a procedure é só executar

```
 exec InserirTudoJunto 'Brasil','Minas Gerais','Belo Horizonte'
```

Obs:quando uma ou mais operações de **insert**/**update**/**delete** dependem de outras, pra não correr o risco que uma funcione e a outra não ,  é importante que elas sejam feitas dentro de uma **transaction**.